# hidden field and checkbox issue on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am working on a page which has checkboxes. When I click on a checkbox, I append the form with its value and create a hidden field.

[image]

This works, however when I press F5, instead of the first checkbox being selected, the second checkbox is selected instead.

Here is the jQuery code.:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').bind('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var html = "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\""+$(this).val()+"\" />"; 
        $('.form').append(html);
    }
});
```

update : if i dont append this hidden field then it is working fine,just a note : checkboxes are outside the form

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue somewhere we could check?

Comment: Where's the code that sets what's selected on the page load?

Comment: @dhsto: there is nothing set on page load

Comment: @All : it was the issue from localhost, when uploaded to server it is working fine. and i dont understand the reason for -1 , as i have already searched the web for the answer but couldnt find thats why i posted it here.

Comment: @Syed I didn't downvote you, but you didn't provide enough information... like your html. It probably would have provided some hints as to why you were having your issue.

Comment: I agree with dhsto that that was probably the reason for the downvote.  However, not including a full code example isn't really a good reason for a downvote - instead, it should prompt a comment asking for the original poster to leave more detail, which is exactly what roasted did above.

Answer (score 0):

are you using the same id for the checkboxes? And are you testing on firefox? Firefox keeps the state of forms on page reload, and if you're using the same id, it will treat the last element it parses as the "one" with that id.